# EOFError: end of file reached Android Ruby Webdriver

Tags: android, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I run the following with an Android emulator and it works, I try it with a real Android device (tested Samsung Galaxy S3 and HTC Wildfire) and I get
EOFError: end of file reached

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

```
gem list
```

shows

```
selenium-client (1.2.18)
selenium-webdriver (2.35.1, 2.34.0, 2.33.0, 2.31.0, 2.27.2)
watir (5.0.0 x86-mingw32, 4.0.2 x86-mingw32, 4.0.0 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (4.0.1, 3.7.0, 3.5.0, 3.2.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4, 0.6.2)
```

amongst others.

I ran the following in both Emulator for Android 4.1.2, a real Samsung Galaxy S3 and a real HTC Wildfire S. The emulator worked and the other two failed in the same manner.

Command line:

> >adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity
>
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity }
>
> >adb forward tcp:8090 tcp:8080

Then Ruby:

```
require 'selenium/client'
require 'watir-webdriver'
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.android
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote,:url=>'http://localhost:8090/wd/hub',:http_client=>client,:desired_capabilities=>capabilities)
driver.navigate.to('http://www.google.co.uk')
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
```

Then with the real device it crashes with

```
EOFError: end of file reached
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:580:in `find_element_by'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
from (irb):19
from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'>>
```

I've tried with real full tests that I have been running with a user agent and am trying to run on actual Android devices too, (which also passed in emulator and errored on real devices) but the above is the simplest example to show the error that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of android-server you were running.

When running the new version of android-server (android-server-2.32.0.apk) I was getting the EOF error on both emulator and real device, but at different points.

I solved the problem by using the previous version of android-server (android-server-2.21.0.apk). My tests are now running without error.